# Checkbox-based selection doesn't work with bootstrap themes

Tags: kendo-ui, bootstrap-4, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo-grid with checkbox-based selection, as per version ^2017.2.621. The selection checkboxes are working until I add bootstrap theme.

The grid is initialized like this:

```
$(this.$refs.kendogrid).kendoGrid({
  dataSource: [
    { id: "1", title: "name 1" },
    { id: "2", title: "name 2" },
    { id: "3", title: "name 3" }
  ],
  columns: [
    { selectable: true },
    { field: "id", title: "ID number" },
    { field: "title", title: "Title" }
  ]
});
```

Then I just import themes:

```
import "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/dist/all.css";
import "bootstrap";
```

And voila - any checkbox now is just a gray field and doesn't react to clicks (and it's not just visual, the selection doesn't work underneath).

Any solutions? Surely someone should have used kendo-grid selection with bootstrap since 2017...

Answer (score -2):

Found the issue: kendo is garbage and full of bugs.

2017.2.621 doesn't work with bootstrap-theming properly because it doesn't create a link between labels and checkboxes, so clicking on a label doesn't change the state of checkbox linked (because it's not linked at all).

One need to upgrade to a newer version or manually fix SELECTCOLUMNTMPL and SELECTCOLUMNHEADERTMPL properties in kendo.grid.js source file.

Comment: Maybe if you provided more info and a [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/) of the issue someone might assist. Kendo is not garbage - it is basically html/js/css underneath. A lot of these types of "bugs" involve how you bundle the various scripts.

Comment: Sapienti sat. The problem is the incorrect column rendering in the said templates in kendo grid source itself. The bug fixed in newer versions, the only little thing here is they are not free. A good style would be to release a bug-fix for the stuff people bought from you. Making people to renew license not for the new features, but for the hope it finally have bugs fixed, is garbage style.